# Multiple steps form with sessions security

Tags: php, security, session

Hi i'm developing a multi steps form with php using session and i've been wondering if there is a way for the user to alter session variables for example on the first page i have something like this :

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];//and so on
}
?>
```

and the other page has something like :

```
<?php
session_start();
$name = $_SESSION['name'];

?>
```

my question is can the user modify the value of the session variable on the second page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're populating the session variable with the value of a POST variable, they can continue to resubmit the first form as much as they want with arbitrary values.

You can use application logic to defeat this:

```
<?php // form1
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['step'])) {
    $_SESSION['step'] = 1;
}
if ($_SESSION['step'] > 1) {
    header("Location: form2.php");
    exit; // This exit is very important, don't neglect it
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];//and so on
    $_SESSION['step'] = 2;
}
```

And then

```
<?php // form2
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['step'])) {
    header("Location: form1.php");
    exit;
}
if ($_SESSION['step'] > 2) {
    header("Location: form3.php");
    exit;
}
if ($_SESSION['step'] < 2) {
    header("Location: form1.php");
    exit;
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

By using application logic, you can control the flow of your visitors within your application.

If you're asking if users can change `$_SESSION` variables outside of any code you've written, the answer is usually no. See also: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31978508/2224584).

Comment: thanks a lot  for this clear answer yes i have to make the user follow the application flow that's it